# Flask-Babel updating of existing messages.pot file

Tags: python, flask, python-babel, flask-babel

How to update an existing messages.pot file?
For example, I have translated messages.pot file:

```
....
#: forms.py:11
msgid "Nickname"
msgstr "Имя"

#: forms.py:18
msgid "Wrong email"
msgstr "Неправильный пароль"
....
```

If I'll mark new text with selector gettext, for example:

```
flash(gettext('Login successful'))
```

and run:
`pybabel extract -F babel.cfg -o messages.pot`
I'll receive a new messages.po file:

```
    ....
#: forms.py:11
msgid "Nickname"
msgstr ""

#: forms.py:18
msgid "Wrong email"
msgstr ""

#: models.py:783
msgid "Login successful"
msgstr ""
....
```

So, how can I **update** an existing messages.pot file, **saving translated strings** ("Nickname", "Wrong email")?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`pot` file not for translations, it just list of all strings for translation without specific language.

For real translations used `po` - text file and `mo` - binary file with translations. This files will created for any languages that you need. See my files structure:

```
translations/
translations/ru/
translations/ru/LC_MESSAGES/
translations/ru/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
translations/ru/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po
translations/messages.pot
```

To get all strings for translation:

```
pybabel extract -F babel.cfg -o messages.pot .
```

To init `po` file (first time):

```
pybabel init -i messages.pot -d . -l ru
```

To update exist `po` file:

```
pybabel update -i messages.pot -d .
```

To compile `po` file to `mo`:

```
pybabel compile -f -d .
```

See more in [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Babel/#translating-applications).